# Как сгруппировать данные при выводе из базы в html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

подскажите как правильно организовать идею:

### У меня есть база locality например такая:

```
id  region  location,   map
1   region1, карусели,  улица пушкина, 1;
2   region1, магазин,   улица пушкина, 2;
3   region2, зоопарк,   фрунзе 1;
4   region2, кинотеатр, фрунзе 3;
5   region2, театр,     улица 1;
6   region3, театр №2,  улица 2;
```

---

В одном region ест уникальные значения location и map, они не повторяются
информацию  я селекчу по id и записываю как mysqli_fetch_array в массив $loc.
как вписать эту информацию правильно в html следующего содержания:

```html
<h3>region1</h3>
<li>Магазин<iframe>улица пушкина, 1</iframe>
<li>магазин<iframe> улица пушкина, 2</iframe>
<h3> region2</h3>
<li>зоопарк <iframe>фрунзе 1</iframe>
<li> кинотеатр <iframe>фрунзе 3</iframe>
```

Не понимаю как сделать цикл что бы при считывании цикл не делал мне что-то типо

```html
<h3>region1</h3>
    <li>Магазин<iframe>улица пушкина, 1</iframe>
<h3>region1</h3>
    <li>магазин<iframe> улица пушкина, 2</iframe>
```

Т.е например

```
<? foreach $loc as $m?>
 <h3><?$m['region']?></h3>
        <li><?$m ['location']?><iframe><?$m ['map']?></iframe>
        <li><?$m ['location']?><iframe><?$m ['map']?></iframe>
//*дальше следующий заголовок той же конструкции.
<? endforeach ?>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь и объяснение как нужно правильно. 
Заранее извиняюсь за возможно не корректный  пример или выражения.Поправьте меня если, что не так или нужно уточнить.

Например у меня такая функция, в которую я записал массив:

```
function loc_array($link){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM  locality';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysqli_error($query));

    if(!$result)
        die(mysqli_error(($link)));
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $loc = array();
    for ($i = 0;$i<$n;$i++)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $loc[] = $row;
   }
    return $loc;
И потом ее вызвал
 $link = db_connect();
    $loc = loc_array($link);
```

Comment: `li` это элемент списка, и входит в теги `ol` или `ul`, без них список работать не будет

Comment: @tCode ну, вообще, как бы будут... другое дело что это ошибка и так делать не стоит... Как я понял, человеку надо просто группировать записи по региону.. 
ТС, выложите свой sql запрос

Comment: @ InDevX да, т.е если сделать GROUP BY region, то при таком цикле не будет повторений вывода записей? в следующем блоке у меня не выйдет тот же регион со 2м значением? Просто я хочу шаблонизировать код, что бы его можно было редактировать и добавлять записи в бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Когда полей много

Решение абсолютно примитивное: выборку надо всего лишь *отсортировать*. Добавив три слова в запрос, `ORDER BY region`. После этого регионы будут идти подряд, и достаточно будет поставить условие как в ответе Timur - если регион сменился, то вывести его:

```
$region = '';
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if ($region != $result['region']) {
        print "<h3>{$result['region']}</h3>";
        $region = $result['region'];
    }
    print "<li>{$result['location']}<iframe>{$result['map']}</iframe></li>";
}
```

Но есть и более удобный вариант. Если вместо убогой mysqli взять нормальный драйвер для работы с БД, то он сможет вернуть данные [*уже сгруппированные по региону*](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group)

```
function loc_array($pdo){
    $query = 'SELECT region, id, location, map FROM  locality';
    return $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
}
```

После этого для вывода будет нужно всего два вложенных цикла

```
<?php foreach ($loc as $region => $chunk): ?>
<h3><?= $region ?></h3>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($chunk as $row): ?>
        <li><?= $row['location']?><iframe><?= $row['map']?></iframe></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

И да, структуру желательно переделать, чтобы у регионов была своя таблица. Но напрямую к вопросу это не относится, с двумя таблицами подход будет тот же самый.

#### Когда полей только два

В самом простом варианте, когда надо запросить только 1 уникальное поле, и к нему - одно поле с группировкой, то можно  воспользоваться запросом с `GROUP BY` и функцией `group_concat()`, которая соберёт все отдельные значения при группировке через запятую

```
SELECT region, group_concat(location) FROM locality GROUP BY region
```

и затем можно будет в РНР скрипте сделать `explode()`:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT region, group_concat(location) loc FROM locality GROUP BY region");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    print "<h3>{$result['region']}</h3>";
    foreach (explode(",", $result['loc']) as $location)
        print "<li>$loсation</li>";
    }
}
```

Но здесь надо помнить про две засады

1. В сгруппированных данных может встретиться замятая, которая устроит ири выводе харакири. Лечится задаванием другого разделителя в group_concat
2. Общая длина строки выдаваемой group_concat ограничена по умолчанию 1024 символами. Лечится запросом `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Но опять же, чтобы избежать всех этих хитросплетений, можно воспользоваться ПДО:

```
function loc_array($pdo){
    $query = 'SELECT region, location FROM locality';
    return $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
```

И выводить

```
<?php foreach ($loc as $region => $locations): ?>
<h3><?= $region ?></h3>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($locations as $item): ?>
        <li><?= $item ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение! с PDO еще не знакомился, видимо нужно с него начинать, во всех источниках ссылаются именно на PDO.

Answer (score 0):

```
<? foreach $loc as $m?>
<h3><?$m['region']?></h3>
<ul>
    <li><?$m ['location']?><iframe><?$m ['map']?></iframe></li>
    <li><?$m ['location']?><iframe><?$m ['map']?></iframe></li>
</ul>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Ознакомьтесь со списками в HTML http://htmlbook.ru/html/ul / http://htmlbook.ru/html/ol

```html
<h3>Region #1</h3>
<ul>
 <li>Content</li>
 <li>Content</li>
</ul>
<h3>Region #2</h3>
<ul>
 <li>Content</li>
 <li>Content</li>
</ul>
<h3>Region #3</h3>
<ul>
 <li>Content</li>
 <li>Content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за поправку в html. У меня вопрос немного другого характера.
Что нужно сделать в php,что бы у меня записи соответствующие значению конкретного региона выводились в список, т.е. название региона и под ним список шел,дальше следующее название региона и тоже список ему соответствующий?

Comment: Если вы не знаете РНР, то не стоит писать ответы под этим тегом.

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
  foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
    if (($strict ? $key === $needle : $key == $needle)) {
        return $key;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

$locality = array();
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

  if ($key = in_array_r($result['region'], $locality)) {
    $result = array_diff($result, [$key]);
    $locality[$key][] = $result;
  } else {
    $region = $result['region'];
    unset($result['region']);
    $locality[$region][] = $result;
  }
}

foreach ($locality as $key => $value) {
  print "<h3>$key</h3>";
  foreach ($value as $val) {
    print "<li>{$val['location']}<iframe>{$val['map']}</iframe></li>";
  }
}
```

Но лучше переделать структуру базы. Примерно так:

```
CREATE TABLE region
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  region VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE locality
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  location VARCHAR(255),
  map VARCHAR(255),
  region_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (region_id)  REFERENCES region (id)
);
```

В этом случае вывод из базы можно организовать так:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM locality LEFT JOIN 
region ON locality.region_id = region.id");

$region = '';

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  if ($region == $result['region']) {
    print "<li>{$result['location']}<iframe>{$result['map']}</iframe 
           </li>";
  } else {
    print "<h3>{$result['region']}</h3>";
    print "<li>{$result['location']}<iframe>{$result['map']}</iframe> 
           </li>";
    $region = $result['region'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ @Timur! действительно, думаю правильным будет переделать структуру базы. Подскажите пожалуйста,если не затруднит. тогда как будет правильным использовать вторичный ключ, как его верно организовать в коде?! действительно, думаю правильным будет переделать структуру базы. Подскажите пожалуйста,если не затруднит. тогда как будет правильным использовать внешний ключ, как его верно организовать в коде?

Comment: @БокийОлег. Добавил в ответ. А запись в базу как обычно

Comment: первое решение мало того что ненужное, но еще и этот ад с рекурсией. второе, что самое смешное, не будет работать в том виде. в котором оно тут написано

Comment: @Ипатьев, почему не будет? я же проверил перед тем как сюда писать

Comment: Проверить мало. Надо еще думать

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну так напиши, почему не будет работать?
Я запускал код, и все норм работает

Comment: @Timur Спасибо за ответ, информация от Вас была полезной! Разобрался в теме более менее. Почитал про нормальные формы. Благодарю за помощь!